# FPDF - How to overwrite first cell by a new one inside foreach

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi I'm using `FPDF` for generating `PDF` file. I'm displaying each item inside my `foreach` using `Cell` function of `FPDF`. Now I have a conditional statement to get the last `iteration` or the last item in my `foreach` and adding a certain value in it. After that I need to overwrite(display) the last iteration with a new value.

[image]

Image Above is the items that I'm displaying. The last item is the last iteration. The first value of the last item is `263.50` and after I get it because it's the last iteration. I'm adding `.01` value on it to be `263.51`.
I can display the new value but the old value is still there.

Here is my sample code

```
$this->SetXY(29, $y);
$this->SetFont('Arial','',8.5);
$this->Cell(18,4,$value_of_ins = str_replace(',', '', number_format($inscost_conv, 2)),1,0,'R'); // this line is to display the items

    if ($i == $len - 1) { // to get the last iteration

    $value_of_ins = $value_of_ins + 1;

    $this->SetXY(29, $y);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',8.5);
    $this->Cell(18,4,$value_of_ins,1,0,'R'); // display the last item with new value

  }
    $i++;
```

Comment: So don't write the last value. First add 0.1, then write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you shouldn't write last value until you add 1 to it. Something like this:

```
$this->SetXY(29, $y);
$this->SetFont('Arial','',8.5);

$value_of_ins = str_replace(',', '', number_format($inscost_conv, 2));
if ($i == $len - 1) {
    $value_of_ins += 1
}

$this->Cell(18,4,$value_of_ins,1,0,'R'); // this line is to display the items
```